# MR.Gestures - Custom View

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gesture-recognition

I am having a SKCanvasView which draws some Graphics and now there is a need to get the tap position. After reading several posts, I decided to implement this via MR.Gestures. Because there is no standard implementation of a SKCanvasView inside the package, I would need to implement it by myself.

My guess was to iherit from **IGestureAwareControl**

```
public class AudioWaveView : SKCanvasView, IGestureAwareControl
```

This one needs to implement a bunch of events and Command:

```
    public GestureHandler GestureHandler { get; }
    public ICommand DownCommand { get; set; }
    public object DownCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand UpCommand { get; set; }
    public object UpCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand TappingCommand { get; set; }
    public object TappingCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand TappedCommand { get; set; }
    public object TappedCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand DoubleTappedCommand { get; set; }
    public object DoubleTappedCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand LongPressingCommand { get; set; }
    public object LongPressingCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand LongPressedCommand { get; set; }
    public object LongPressedCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand PinchingCommand { get; set; }
    public object PinchingCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand PinchedCommand { get; set; }
    public object PinchedCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand PanningCommand { get; set; }
    public object PanningCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand PannedCommand { get; set; }
    public object PannedCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand SwipedCommand { get; set; }
    public object SwipedCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand RotatingCommand { get; set; }
    public object RotatingCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public ICommand RotatedCommand { get; set; }
    public object RotatedCommandParameter { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler<DownUpEventArgs> Down;
    public event EventHandler<DownUpEventArgs> Up;
    public event EventHandler<TapEventArgs> Tapping;
    public event EventHandler<TapEventArgs> Tapped;
    public event EventHandler<TapEventArgs> DoubleTapped;
    public event EventHandler<LongPressEventArgs> LongPressing;
    public event EventHandler<LongPressEventArgs> LongPressed;
    public event EventHandler<PinchEventArgs> Pinching;
    public event EventHandler<PinchEventArgs> Pinched;
    public event EventHandler<PanEventArgs> Panning;
    public event EventHandler<PanEventArgs> Panned;
    public event EventHandler<SwipeEventArgs> Swiped;
    public event EventHandler<RotateEventArgs> Rotating;
    public event EventHandler<RotateEventArgs> Rotated;
```

I am not sure if this is the way to go, but it looks like a good starting point, but now I am stuck and don't know how to go further. Has anyone made such a similar thing or knows the solution?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [Microsoft's Touch Manipulations article regarding SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch). It uses an Effect to support touch operations, more details on effects here: [Invoking Events from Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking)

Basically you need to add a TouchEffect to the container in which your CanvasView is added (or even add the effect to your CanvasView, there's an example like this in article linked above):

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="1">
    <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView" PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
    <Grid.Effects>
        <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True" TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
    </Grid.Effects>
</Grid>
```

And then add a handler for TouchAction event, as below. You need to first convert the touch point to pixels and then check if

```
void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
{
        if (args.Type != TouchActionType.Pressed)
        {
            return;
        }

        var pointLocation = args.Location;
        var point =
            new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pointLocation.X / canvasView.Width),
                        (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pointLocation.Y / canvasView.Height));

        // TODO: Handle your touch here
}
```

Comment: This works quiet well, no need to use MR.Gestures. Is there a extension which supports left and right Mouse Buttons, multiple fingers, etc without needing to code that by myself?

Comment: It does support 2 fingers touch for sure, check out the TwoFingerManipulate method in the first article